# how to make rounded corners for image in android ?

Tags: android

how to make a rounder corners for image view in android ??

Answer (score 3):

actually you have to include selector file under drawable folder..

i give u one example coding ,make appropriate changes

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
         <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF0000"/>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <corners 
                android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" 
                android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="30dp" 
                android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>
    </shape>
```

android:background="@drawable/selector.xml"

Comment: but the iamge still rectangle shape ?!?!

Answer (score 0):

have u tried like this?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/selector.xml">
    <Imageview
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:background="@drawable/image.png"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```